# Unsupported Image Format when trying to load an image from a response body

Tags: rust, image-uploading

Starting from the [gotham-rs routing example](https://github.com/gotham-rs/gotham/tree/master/examples/routing), I am trying to make a REST API that extracts an image from a request body so that it can be analyzed.  I upload the image to the server with the following cURL command:

```
curl -i -X POST -F "image=@/Users/DanielBank/Desktop/grace_hopper.jpg" http://127.0.0.1:7878/
```

I get an unsupported image format error when I try to load the image from memory:

```
thread 'gotham-worker-0' panicked at 'called `Result::unwrap()` on an `Err` value: UnsupportedError("Unsupported image format")', src/libcore/result.rs:999:5
```

**/src/main.rs**:

```
extern crate futures;
extern crate gotham;
extern crate hyper;
extern crate mime;
extern crate url;

use futures::{future, Future, Stream};
use hyper::{Body, StatusCode};

use gotham::handler::{HandlerFuture, IntoHandlerError};
use gotham::helpers::http::response::create_response;
use gotham::router::builder::{build_simple_router, DefineSingleRoute, DrawRoutes};
use gotham::router::Router;
use gotham::state::{FromState, State};

use tract_core::ndarray;
use tract_core::prelude::*;

/// Extracts the image from a POST request and responds with a prediction tuple (probability, class)
fn prediction_handler(mut state: State) -> Box<HandlerFuture> {
  let f = Body::take_from(&mut state)
    .concat2()
    .then(|full_body| match full_body {
      Ok(valid_body) => {
        // load the model
        let mut model = tract_tensorflow::tensorflow()
          .model_for_path("mobilenet_v2_1.4_224_frozen.pb")
          .unwrap();

        // specify input type and shape
        model
          .set_input_fact(
            0,
            TensorFact::dt_shape(f32::datum_type(), tvec!(1, 224, 224, 3)),
          )
          .unwrap();

        // optimize the model and get an execution plan
        let model = model.into_optimized().unwrap();
        let plan = SimplePlan::new(&model).unwrap();
        let body_content = valid_body.into_bytes();

        // extract the image from the body as input
        let image = image::load_from_memory(body_content.as_ref())
          .unwrap()
          .to_rgb();
        let resized = image::imageops::resize(&image, 224, 224, ::image::FilterType::Triangle);
        let image: Tensor = ndarray::Array4::from_shape_fn((1, 224, 224, 3), |(_, y, x, c)| {
          resized[(x as _, y as _)][c] as f32 / 255.0
        })
        .into();

        // run the plan on the input
        let result = plan.run(tvec!(image)).unwrap();

        // find and display the max value with its index
        let best = result[0]
          .to_array_view::<f32>()
          .unwrap()
          .iter()
          .cloned()
          .zip(1..)
          .max_by(|a, b| a.0.partial_cmp(&b.0).unwrap());

        // respond with the prediction tuple
        let res = create_response(
          &state,
          StatusCode::OK,
          mime::TEXT_PLAIN,
          format!("{:?}", best.unwrap()),
        );
        future::ok((state, res))
      }
      Err(e) => future::err((state, e.into_handler_error())),
    });

  Box::new(f)
}

/// Create a `Router`
fn router() -> Router {
  build_simple_router(|route| {
    route.post("/").to(prediction_handler);
  })
}

/// Start a server and use a `Router` to dispatch requests
pub fn main() {
  let addr = "127.0.0.1:7878";
  println!("Listening for requests at http://{}", addr);
  gotham::start(addr, router())
}
```

**Cargo.toml**:

```
[package]
name = "offline-ml"
description = "Offline ML but with a REST API that's not Offline"
version = "0.1.0"
authors = ["Daniel Bank"]
edition = "2018"

# See more keys and their definitions at https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/manifest.html

[dependencies]
futures = "0.1"
gotham = "0.4.0"
hyper = "0.12"
image = "0.22.2"
mime = "0.3"
tract-core = "0.4.2"
tract-tensorflow = "0.4.2"
url = "2.1.0"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the request body has both http headers and image data. You need to parse it somehow according to [RFC 7578](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7578).

Surprisingly I couldn't find a ready-made decent MIME multipart/form-data parser crate. The following code works, but it resorts to extremely crude `regex` split instead of proper parsing. Also, it omits the tensor model training part:

```rust
extern crate image;
extern crate mime;

use futures::{future, Future, Stream};
use gotham::handler::{HandlerFuture, IntoHandlerError};
use gotham::helpers::http::response::create_response;
use gotham::router::builder::{build_simple_router, DefineSingleRoute, DrawRoutes};
use gotham::router::Router;
use gotham::state::{FromState, State};
use hyper::{Body, StatusCode};
use regex::bytes::Regex;

fn prediction_handler(mut state: State) -> Box<HandlerFuture> {
    let f = Body::take_from(&mut state)
        .concat2()
        .then(|full_body| match full_body {
            Ok(valid_body) => {
                let body_content = valid_body.into_bytes();
                let re = Regex::new(r"\r\n\r\n").unwrap();
                let contents: Vec<_> = re.split(body_content.as_ref()).collect();

                let image = image::load_from_memory(contents[1]).unwrap().to_rgb();

                let res = create_response(
                    &state,
                    StatusCode::OK,
                    mime::TEXT_PLAIN,
                    format!("{:?}\r\n", image.dimensions()),
                );
                future::ok((state, res))
            }
            Err(e) => future::err((state, e.into_handler_error())),
        });

    Box::new(f)
}
```